# Quantum Entanglement as a Paradox

Tags: photons, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, crystals

Photon splitting, also known as spontaneous parametric down-conversion, is a process where a single high-energy photon can split into two lower-energy entangled photons. This process occurs in a nonlinear crystal, where the photons interact with the crystal lattice.

Is it possible that the crystal lattice is so perfectly symmetric that when energy is added to it in the form of the photon’s wave function, that a portion of the wave causes the creation of an atomic wormhole within the lattice which splits the photon into an entangled pair, but whereby the entangled pair creates a paradox whereby the same photon exists both as itself and as an extension of itself at a separate point in time that happens to be at an extremely small delta time from the present (as some of its wave has propagated through a wormhole within the crystal), so that when one photon’s spin is determined, the paradox then collapses into a determinate universe? In other words, the spin is defined by the observation in order to correct the error in the universe you currently exist, or perhaps another way of thinking of it would be that, there may be multiple universes and that the act of simply observing defines which universe you are in?

Comment: I have no idea what most of this means, but it doesn't seem like it would be very remarkable for the same photon to exist at two different points in time.  I've existed at quite a few different points in time myself.

Comment: @WillO To help you understand my question, I have edited it with: whereby the same photon exists both as itself and as an extension of itself at a separate point in time that happens to be at an extremely small delta time from the present

Comment: @Alwxandru : I do that too.  I existed (in a slightly different form) a very short time ago, and hope to exist a very short time from now.

Comment: @WillO I’m sorry but you didn’t understand the spirit of the question. There isn’t a good analogy to explain it with reference to a human body, because we don’t, AFAIK, exhibit the ability to collapse ourselves into a wave or to break ourselves in two half density versions of ourselves, but if we could, it would be like, half of our wave taking a wormhole, while half does not. So, half of us exists as a clone of ourselves with half our density in a paradox reality where the other half density self also exists.

Answer (score 1):

The nonlinear process in the crystal produces entangled photon pairs, but the reason for the entanglement is the fact that energy and momentum needs to be conserved. It does not need a wormhole for that. All the wormhole and multiverse stuff comes from speculative ideas without any scientific support. In other words, there is no experimental observations that support the ideas of wormhole or multiple universes. On the other hand, the entanglement of photons produced in such experiments has been confirmed experimentally.